# flyway migration naming convention

Tags: flyway

I've inherited a mature flyway implementation and am trying to make a change to how migrations are named. Currently the migrations are automatically named with ascending, auto incremented naming convention like:

```
x.yyy.z
```

We can manually apply a migration, but it must not be out of sequence or we get a checksum error. We'd like to start naming each applied migration with the build number so the migrations don't have to be named in sequential order. Seems like the checksum should render sequential names irrelevant.

How do I configure flyway to ignore the migration name?

Answer (score 0):

Use `outOfOrder` as per the [Flyway documentation](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/migrate):

> Allows migrations to be run "out of order".
>
> If you already have versions 1 and 3 applied, and now a version 2 is found, it will be applied too instead of being ignored.